# Reference sqlite Database in App.config

Tags: c#, winforms

Edit Question: 
Sorry about this basic question. This is a new technology to me.

I am using a c#, winforms application with sqlite.
Currently I have included sqliteDb in app_data folder, Also App.Config has the connection string:

```
<connectionStrings>
<clear/>
<add name ="RConnString"
providerName="System.Data.Sqlite"
connectionString="Data Source= C:\project1\R1\App_Data\RVEST_V1.DB"/>
</connectionStrings>
This RconnString is being accessed in .cs file. 
  string connString = 

ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RConnString"].ConnectionString;
```

When I send it to client, How would I send the database. I mean how should I change the connection string.( Instead of referring to my local C:..)

Thank you
Sun

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using relative path like this

`connectionString="Data Source=App_Data\RVEST_V1.DB"`

Comment: Are you sure you are using winforms and not webforms? When you create webforms you get App_Data folder.

Comment: I am using winforms. The solution did not have a app_data when I created it. I added the App_data folder. Not sure if a databse should go in the app_data folder for a winforms application. What would be the best place for the database.The application is very light weight